# migrating to python from R: specific questions

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I have been using R and RStudio for prototyping and model building and due to some persisting problems (which would only be applicable to the environment that I am using in) we have decided to use python. I am looking to know:

1. is there a python development environment like "RStudio Server"?
2. how easy/hard to enable multi-threading/multi-core processing in
   Python for decision trees/gradient boosting?
3. can data persist in python dev environment server? Meaning: Can I save the dev environment with code and data frames and come back the
   next
       day to access/pick up where I left?
4. Can you connect to Oracle database from Python?
5. Is there a way I can import .RData to python development
       environment?

**Why ask these questions here?**

While looking up on search engines, I am mostly getting unreliable results, training insitutes promotions, outdated blogs and whitepapers from industry giants. I need a reliable answer.

Comment: 2): Algos in sklearn and also the interfaces to XGBoost and lightGBM are as parallelized as their analogons in R.

Answer (score 1):

1) Anaconda Spyder, maybe

2) sklearn, random forest has an option to select the number of jobs, and it will take care of parallelizing

3) i don't think so, but you can pickle objects and load them up. you can probably do something like create a variable_name - value dictionary and just pickle that

4) never tried

5) according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288133/loading-rdata-files-into-python, I don't think so

Comment: Why pickling when you have feather format?

Answer (score 0):

I can try to answer the 3rd question. You can use Jupyter + Python Kernel (install [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python) to use conda commands with python Kernel). Jupyter allows keep your code and notes and graphs in one notebook and save it.